# Excel Pivot Table macro to use on multiple worksheets with dynamic ranges

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I create a report every month at work that parses sales out by product family.  Due to the limitations within the report I use for the data, I can't simply use a pivot table to get the data I need for my report.  I slice the data into separate worksheets by product family.  The number of rows on each sheet vary depending upon the number of customers that bought product in that product family.  I currently have a macro that I run each time I create a new sheet that does sums, sumproduct and sumif procedures.  I want to also add a pivot table at the bottom of the data on each sheet for further manipulation.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, but my code isn't working.  Here it is:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "ActiveSheet.Name!R1C1:R231C30", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "ActiveSheet.Name!R237C3", TableName:="PivotTable21", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("ActiveSheet.Name").Select
Cells(237, 3).Select
```

Comment: try avoiding using `ActiveSheet` , you will get errors running this code while you are working on a different sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!R1C1:R231C30", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "'" & ActiveSheet.Name & "'!R237C3", TableName:="PivotTable21", DefaultVersion:=6

Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Select 'Seems redundant here?
Cells(237, 3).Select
```

You need the single quotes in case the sheet name has spaces.